# Is there a collection or list of all planned observations of 99942 Apophis during its 2021 close pass to Earth?

Tags: observational-astronomy, asteroids, radar, 99942-apophis, observation-campaign

For example, I found [Goldstone Radar Observations Planning: 99942 Apophis in 2021](https://echo.jpl.nasa.gov/asteroids/Apophis/apophis.2021.goldstone.planning.html) and [99942 Apophis 2021; Planned, Scheduled and Completed Observations](https://iawn.net/obscamp/Apophis/apophis_obs.shtml) at lawn.com? which seems empty.

But I'll bet the observation campaign for this important event by various means (radar, optical, infrared...) was well coordinated. Because of the potential long-term risk of impact with Earth it's necessary to learn as much as possible about [99942 Apophis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/99942_Apophis).

Comment: [Should we have an campaign tag and what is goo usage advice for it?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/715/7982)