# Is an "observation campaign" well recognized thing in Astronomy? Is it self-declared? Are there standard ways to announce or coordinate?

Tags: observational-astronomy, amateur-observing, observation-campaign

The Astronomy meta question [Should we have an observation-campaign tag and what is good usage advice for it?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/715/7982) lists about 13 example questions where the tag might apply. There are several answers that evoke the term here as well, but tags go on questions (primarily).

In it I wrote:

> My understanding is that it is anything between a rally for amateur observers to try to photograph something to a highly coordinated and preplanned observing plan for ground and space observatories and facilities, but that's just my impression.

A "star party" is not an observational campaign because the primary goals are outreach, fun, and general Astronomy education. A campaign would be a targeted and to some extent coordinated effort, at least to the extent that it was announced and described ahead of time. It could certainly *involve* amateur astronomers or even the public, but it would still presumably have at least some research or scientific goal,

**Question(s):**

1. Is an "observation campaign" well recognized thing in Astronomy?
2. Is it self-declared? Do people just come up with them and announce them?
3. Are there standard ways to announce or coordinate them?

Comment: My 50 cents: For movable equipment like SOFIA there are definitely campaigns. Also for sites which require a big team working together to be able to measure like AMANDA in Antarctia. Also at ESO for dedicated project weeks where a group of scientists flies over to co-locate and works with a clear goal on a well-defined scope, e.g. calibrating a primary mirror.

Comment: @B--rian are there examples of multi-site campaigns, where for example several distant observatories coordinate to provide continuous coverage of a target as the Earth rotates them one-by-one into favorable position?

Comment: Observing campaigns occur regularly for Solar System objects e.g. https://iawn.net/obscamp/Apophis/ There have also been regular campaigns for long period exoplanet transits, pulsating white dwarfs (see Whole Earth Telescope) and eclipsing binaries

Comment: @astrosnapper the second link in [Is there a collection or list of all planned observations of 99942 Apophis during its 2021 close pass to Earth?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/43190/7982) references lawn.net but since I couldn't find an actual list that wasn't empty I wasn't sure if the site is what I'd thought it was. Should I expect a list of radio and optical observations there?

Comment: Top link of https://iawn.net/obscamp/Apophis/apophis_obs.shtml has this but it's self reported and likely not kept uptodate

Comment: @astrosnapper okay got it, yes `Last updated: Friday October 09, 2020`